# MYSQL deleting a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing some more revision, how do the following:

Delete the Beetle belonging to “A Wilks”

```
person (driver-id, name, address)
car (license, model, year)
accident (report-number, date, location)
owns (driver-id, license) 
participated (driver-id, car, report-number, damage-amount)
```

here is what I have come up with:

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE model = 'beetle'
```

however I know this is wrong because it will delete all the beetle cars and not just the one owned by A Wilks.

Comment: Can you write a (`SELECT`) query to show the cars that are `'beetle'` and have owner `'A'`? If yes, it's easy to turn the query into a `DELETE` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE model = 'beetle'
AND license = (
    SELECT o.license from owns o INNER JOIN person p
    ON o.driver-id = p.driver-id
    WHERE p.name = 'A Wilks'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE model = 'Beetle' AND license IN (
  SELECT license
  FROM owns
  INNER JOIN Person ON owns.driver_id = person.driver_id
  WHERE person_name = 'A Wilks'
```

You could use `license =` instead of `license IN` on the second line of the query if you're sure there will be just one Beetle belonging to "A Wilks".

And please consider sitting down with a copy of MySQL and trying some of the queries; you'll learn the material better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM car 
USING car 
INNER JOIN owns 
INNER JOIN person
WHERE car.license=owns.license 
AND car.model='Beetle'
AND owns.driver-id=person.driver-id 
AND person.name='A Wilks';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///delete.html

Answer (score 0):

`delete from car 
where model ='beetle' and licence=(select licence owns
  INNER JOIN Person ON owns.driver_id = person.driver_id
  WHERE person_name = 'A Wilks')`

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Philippinedev was a good one and I wanted to note why it is a better technique than the answers that use a subquery.

His answer uses join syntax (best performance and control):

```
DELETE FROM car 
USING car 
INNER JOIN owns 
INNER JOIN person
WHERE car.license=owns.license 
AND car.model='Beetle'
AND owns.driver-id=person.driver-id 
AND person.name='A Wilks';
```

He's using the syntax that performs a query with joined tables, and deletes any matching records in the table from the DELETE FROM  clause.  The alternative approach uses the sub-query format (**easy to code, poorer performance**):

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE model = 'beetle'
AND license = (
    SELECT o.license from owns o INNER JOIN person p
    ON o.driver-id = p.driver-id
    WHERE p.name = 'A Wilks'
)
```

Sub-queries are more expensive in performance than straight joins.  If this were a query being run on a real Department of Motor Vehicles system (with millions of records), you would want to avoid using sub-queries at all costs, and use straight-up joins instead.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you add owner to car and do:

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE model = 'beetle' and owner = 'ownername'
```

This will not work unless you have the `owner` included in `car`.

Comment: you can't have two WHERE's in sql. So you should get rid of one of those

Comment: okay thanks! I noticed another person had tow WHERE's so I assumed that I was doing it wrong..... turned out i was right! Thanks @greedybuddha !